# How do I download large file with streaming in AFNetworking 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-3

I want to download large file using AFNetworking 3. But I need to resume download while there is any interruption like internet loss or any other things. If any interrupts while downloading I want to start download from where it stop early. Is it possible using AFNetworking or do I use any other libraries? Please anybody help me.
Here is my code.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:formattedURL];

//Watch the manager to see how much of the file it's downloaded
[manager setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    //Convert totalBytesWritten and totalBytesExpectedToWrite into floats so that percentageCompleted doesn't get rounded to the nearest integer
    CGFloat written = totalBytesWritten;
    CGFloat total = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    CGFloat percentageCompleted = written/total;

    //Return the completed progress so we can display it somewhere else in app
    //progressBlock(percentageCompleted);
    NSLog(@"Percentage Completed : %f",percentageCompleted);
    [self updateProgressBar:percentageCompleted];
}];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    //Getting the path of the document directory
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    NSURL *fullURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"3511_1464694276.zip"];

    //If we already have a video file saved, remove it from the phone
    return fullURL;
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //If there's no error, return the completion block
        //completionBlock(filePath);
    } else {
        //Otherwise return the error block
        //errorBlock(error);
    }

}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: Yes. I have update it.

Comment: It is not working. When I turn off the internet and then turn on that code is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Read more about it here : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

And try to ask questions when you have written some code or tried something on your own.

**Download file with progress :**

```
- (IBAction)downloadAudio:(id)sender {



    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://101songs.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/26958.mp3"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update the progress view
            [_myProgressView setProgress:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted];

        });



    } destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        // Do operation after download is complete

    }];
    [downloadTask resume];


}
```

Comment: I am using AFNetworking 3 and didn't see any streaming download in it. is it my mistake?

Comment: @Binni you want to see the progress ? or your file isn't downloading ?

Comment: Yes.. I want to see the progress and already it is working with the existing code. But I need also streaming download.

Comment: @Binni try above code. And if you disconnect the internet connection it is supposed to stop due to server error. If you send your app in background and bring it in foreground again you can see you download task is started where it was left.

Comment: I don't want to pause or resume the download while the app go to the background. I only want to start download from where it stops in the case of internet connection loss or app force close.

Comment: @Binni In that case what you are doing is not enough. 
If app is killed : you have to maintain the background tasks. 
So learn more about background fetching.

Comment: Yes. you are correct.. should I need to download status locally before closing??

Comment: @Binni I am not sure about that so cant give advice on that. You can google for background fetching.