# How to resume download a large file with afnetworking 3

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-3

i want to resume download a large file. And the interface is not suitable:

```
downloadTaskWithResumeData
```

because it's not working when the app crashed.

the answer [How do I download large file with streaming in AFNetworking 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698417/how-do-i-download-large-file-with-streaming-in-afnetworking-3)   does not resove the problem.

The afnetworking 2.0 can set the outputstream, but i don't know how to set the outputstream in 3.0.

so i really need your help.